# Problems with Vlookup, Arrays and Collections. in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

Okay so a bit of context to this one. I have some code that sorts through a list of locations of parts, to create a dropdown list locations that can be selected and will be used elsewhere for sorting later on. The location is a 9 digit code and I am trying to use VLookup to find the corresponding name to its location code from a different sheet, Combining them into an array and then displays that array in a combo box.

I am currently getting a "Subscript out of range" error on the line containing the VLookup.

```
Locan2(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(Locan(i), Sheet16.Range("A2:D700"), 2, False)
```

I have included below the whole subroutine for context, any help would be appreciated this is annoying me greatly and I can't find anything similar from my searches.

```
Private Sub Compbox() '<============Populates Location Drop down list==============>
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim Locn As String
Dim Locan() As String
Dim Locan2() As String
Dim Location As Collection

lastrow = Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row 'Find length of Sheet5
Set Location = New Collection

For i = 4 To lastrow
    Locn = Sheet5.Cells(i, 10).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Location.Add (Locn), CStr(Locn)          'Add location values, ignore duplicates
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
i = 0
    QuickSort Location, 1, Location.Count     'Sort into ascending order

    CollectionToArray Location, Locan         'Turn into an array
    ReDim Locan2(UBound(Locan), 2)

    For i = 0 To UBound(Locan)
        Locan2(i, 0) = Locan(i)
        Locan2(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(Locan(i), Sheet16.Range("A2:D700"), 2, False)
    Next i
                                      'Find the corresponding location name and create a 2D array

With Me.ComboBox2
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .BoundColumn = 1                   'display combo box
    .ColumnWidths = "1 in; 3in"
    .List = Locan
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: debug.print Locan(i) is this in your search range?

Comment: do you really have `Sheet16` ? don't you prefer to work with the name of the worksheet ? What do you do if `VLookup` fails ? if it can't find a match ?  you need to trap the error

Comment: See [Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27748/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range#t=201701271549269588544) on Documentation.SO.

Comment: Try using .... Locan2(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(Locan(i), Sheets("Sheet16").Range("A2:D700"), 2, False)

Comment: Also do yourself a long-term favour, and use more descriptive variable names. They are very similar - Locan, Locn, Locan2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is some flaw in your logic in these steps:

```
QuickSort Location, 1, Location.Count
CollectionToArray Location, Locan         'Turn into an array
ReDim Locan2(UBound(Locan), 2)
```

Potentially an off-by-one error or maybe no allocated arr is being returned?

I notice you are using custom VBA functions to sort the collection and transform to Array.

Why not use built-in ArrayList object?

```
Dim Location As mscorlib.ArrayList
Dim Locan As Variant

Set Location = New mscorlib.ArrayList

For i = 4 To lastrow
    Locn = Sheet5.Cells(i, 10).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Location.Add CStr(Locn)          'ArrayList has the add function too!
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

Location.Sort               'Has the sort function built-in too!
Locan = Location.toArray    'And the toArray function is built-in too!!
```

That may assist you if you are doing standard quicksort and stand toArray functionality.

I left the full Object declaration so you can see you need to add a reference to the mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're going past the last index of Locan2, I would put a breakpoint in on that line and take a look at the value of i. Difficult to say more without having the whole sheet in front of me.

Comment: Use UBound(locan)+1 to set Locan2 as Ubound returns a 0 based value. Eg A UBound of array with 1 element returns 0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.90).aspx